# Running JAVA code using oozie workflow

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I have a java application and I want to run it as an action in my workflow.
I am aware that I can run a JAVA class in a JAVA action node, but is there a way that I can run a JAVA application having many classes in my workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oozie is a workflow co-ordinator which lets you executes any action i.e. pig,hive, java class or shell script.

The Java action will execute the `public static void main(String[] args)` method of the specified main Java class.

And following is the syntax for Java action:

```
<action name='java1'>
    <java>
     ...
          <main-class> a.b.c.MyJavaMain </main-class>
          .......   
          <arg> arg1 </arg>
          <arg> arg2 </arg>
      ...
    </java>
  </action>
```

It's quite visible that you need to pass **main-class** name here.

If you have multiple main classes to execute in one application, you can create multiple Java actions accordingly.

For more details, refer [Oozie Java actions](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.7_Java_Action)